# Dividing request link into two parts

Tags: iphone, xcode, https

I have provided GET request. Inside API string I should put some data, which I'm getting after 
running the app, so I need to divide my whole string in two parts, and put my result, which is resultText in between. So I've made it with startQuery and endQuery. But I have a failure, while bilding this app. Hope somebody have an idea. Here is some ScreenShots: 
[image: Failure]
[image: XCode description]

```
- (void)makeRequest
{
    if (_responseData == nil)
    {
        _responseData = [NSMutableData new];
    }

    NSString* startQuery = [NSString stringWithString:@"https://www.wikifood.eu/wikifood/en/struts/xxxxxxxx.do?method=getProductOverview&query="];
    NSString* endQuery = [NSString stringWithString:@"&startAt=0&limit=5&filter=true&loginname=xxxxxx&password=6f052cxxx15a4c2813baf3x75xx51dead1f4fe2"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", startQuery, resultText.text, endQuery] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    _urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two warnings you're seeing are because you're using `NSString stringWithString` when you could just use a literal string.

Replace:

```
NSString* startQuery = [NSString stringWithString:@"https://www.wikifood.eu/wikifood/en/struts/xxxxxxxx.do?method=getProductOverview&query="];
NSString* endQuery = [NSString stringWithString:@"&startAt=0&limit=5&filter=true&loginname=xxxxxx&password=6f052cxxx15a4c2813baf3x75xx51dead1f4fe2"];
```

With:

```
NSString* startQuery = @"https://www.wikifood.eu/wikifood/en/struts/xxxxxxxx.do?method=getProductOverview&query=";
NSString* endQuery = @"&startAt=0&limit=5&filter=true&loginname=xxxxxx&password=6f052cxxx15a4c2813baf3x75xx51dead1f4fe2";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you're adding percent escape :
    stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding

But you're doing it on the whole string... I think you meant :

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", startQuery, [resultText.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], endQuery]];
```

You're URL doesn't need to be escaped, you know it, it is ok, just your "unsafe" text

Again : not sure, I've not opened XCode to try ^^